# Application crashed due to empty database

Tags: android, sqlite

> when i am pressing the btn app is crashing beacause there is no data in the database .

```
   public void viewBtn(View v){


   try {

    Intent  i2 = new Intent(this,view.class);


   startActivityForResult(i2,500);


   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 

} catch (Exception e) {


    Toast.makeText(this,"Add Some Course First ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

> View.class
>   this class is to  show data from db . when i am tring to show this page when the db is empty app is crshing

```
       public class view extends Activity  {
        final Context context = this;
    ListView l;
    String m;
   int pos;
   public  String s,kk;
   TextView resultShow;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.view);
resultShow=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
 l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,readRecords()));






 }

 ArrayList<String> readRecords(){
     ArrayList<String> record = new ArrayList<String>(); 


     SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("newDb",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String sql = "SELECT * from newTabb;";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        double ss;
        double sumOfGr=0;
        int sumOfCr=0;
        while (c.moveToNext()){

            String i ;

            String semester = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Semester"));

            String course = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Course"));
            double grade = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Grade"));
            int credit=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Credit"));

            ss=credit*grade;

            sumOfCr=sumOfCr+credit;
            sumOfGr=sumOfGr+ss;

            i = "Semester: "+semester+"  Course: "+course+"  Grade: "+grade;

            m = "Semester:"+semester+"\nCourse: "+course+"\nGrade: "+grade+"\nCreadit: "+credit;

            record.add(i);




        }

        double cgpa=sumOfGr/sumOfCr;

        String.format("%.2f", cgpa);


        //s="CGPA : "+cgpa;



  resultShow.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(cgpa));


 l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i,
            long r) {

         pos=i;

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);


            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Details");


            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(m)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Back",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                }

                            });


            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


            alertDialog.show();


        }


 });
return record;



 }



 public  String getCgpa(){

     return s;
 }
```

}

[image]

Comment: ... and where is the **relevant** code?

Comment: this is too ambiguous. Your code don't have any db operation!

Comment: From the LogCat you screenshot (**why a screenshot??**), it doesn't find a table named `newTabb`.

Comment: Your db don't have `newTabb` table!

Comment: You should post your table creation code.

Comment: **1** - Please, format your code- **2** - Where is your **CREATE TABLE** code?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your application from the device and run it again. When ever you add a new table in your database. The easy way is to uninstall application and install it again to test. Since device kept your old database. And in most of the cases it wont add new table.

Answer (score 1):

See your logcat. You will find a line in **logcat** error like **"caused by:"**. Here it's saying that you didn't create any table like 'newTabb".

Please add this line:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTabb(Semester VARCHAR,Course VARCHAR,Grade REAL,Credit INTEGER);");
```

After this line:

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("newDb",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: Try to make a db java file seperately. It will help you to avoid problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Install asqlitemanager from playstore load up your database to check for its integrity..I get the same error whenever I modify tables just wipe data for your app that should do it.